# For a given salt, is the OpenBSD bcrypt strong hashing function a mathematical injection?

Tags: encryption, bcrypt

Meaning, for a given salt, and any two non-equal strings, will the two resulting BCrypt hashes always be non-equal? I assume that it is an injection, but I was wondering if a proof exists. Thanks!

Comment: It *cannot* be an injection, there must be collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at bcrypt digest size: it’s 184 bits (23 bytes), so you can have 2^184 different bcrypt hashes.

If I take as an input only 23 byte long strings, the bcrypt *can* happen to be an injection (most likely it will not be), but even if it is an injection, adding just one more string with the length != 23 bytes to the inputs necessitates a collision.

This is an application of [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)